# Why do Animorphs have a two hour limit?

Tags: animorphs, morphing

Why is there a two hour time limit on a morph? Is there anything in canon that explains why?

Comment: You shouldn't ask for "theories". This is a Q&A site, for questions that have a single correct answer. Not conjecture, opinions etc. Other than that, it's a good question though...

Comment: Please don't ask open-ended questions of this nature. If you want to know if there was any official explanation given within the show itself, that question would be fine, but as-is, it's "too broad" and probably going to be closed.

Comment: More bizarre to me (and a general pet peeve in fictional media), why does it work on an even number of Earth time units?

Comment: As I recall, you can morph for more than two hours. You just can't go back after that time. Kinda like a pawn shop.

Comment: @SeanDuggan, it doesn't, of course. "I am actually speaking Rigellian.  By an astonishing coincidence both of our languages are exactly the same."

Comment: @SeanDuggan Do we know that the number wasn't rounded down to the nearest Earth-unit when it was explained to them?  I can't remember any instances of someone attempting to morph right after the two-hour window, and being trapped.  The only instance of someone being trapped in a morph(as far as I remember) is Tobias, who was well past the two-hour limit.

Comment: @Liesmith:
It's been years since I read the books, but I think I remember someone transforming exactly at the two hour mark (I want to say from a rhinoceros for some reason) and finding it almost impossible to finish the morph.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Fine, twist my arm why dontcha...I guess I'll just *have* to re-read the entire series.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots It isn't an even number, or even a solid number.  Twice during the series they accidentally went a some minutes past the limit and demorphing took a lot of extra effort.  (One was very early as wolves, the other was late in the series with a dragonfly and the others riding on it I think as fleas)

Answer (score 15):

It is explained, although not in great detail.

Morphing is performed using an "Escafil device" or "Andalite morphing cube". This is a device made by a people known as the "Andalites".

We're never told how and why this works, or why there is such a limitation: it is simply a limitation of the technology. I believe there is a reference at one stage to Andelite scientists attempting to improve the technology.

It appears, therefore, to be something akin to a battery life or capacitor capacity.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is as upvoted as it is.  The actual cube is not required once you have touched it to gain the ability.  This isn't a thing where the heroes have to 'recharge' their morphing tech each time they change.

Comment: @Jeff It actually makes sense. Technology guess here. The morphing technology transforms you and makes a backup of your body and DNA. While you are morphed, the inmune system of the morph tries to get rid of the nanobots that are protecting that backup copy and enough energy to morph back with something akin to an energy shield. the two hour limit time is the duration of the energy shield. After the two hours are finished, the nanobots will begin to use the energy to get back to the original morph, effectively trapping you as a nothlit.

Answer (score 14):

The original body is stored in Zero-Space. During book 18 there was a glitch and the party members were stuck in zero-space and rescued by a passing Andalite ship. This would strongly imply that the limit was because of the body in hyperspace only lasting for 2 hours.

Comment: I believe they called it Z-Space, or Zero-Space. And the way they explained it was that the extra mass you lose when morphing into something small is stored there.

Answer (score -5):

Possibly the DNA will permanently transform into the animal you morphed. I'm not sure; I'm just an Animorphs nerd with a theory.